# Unable to connect to appcenter server from android device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

1. We have deployed IBM App Center (from IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0) for Android in our Application Center.
2. Log on the Application Center install site to download IBM App Center.
3. Downloaded and installed IBM App Center to Mobile device and installed successfully.
4. When trying to log on to IBM AppCenter (mobile app) on the Mobile device, we get the following error:

> Error on mobile device: "connection failed. check your connection details (http status 404)" 
>   Trace_log: "[1/13/17 13:14:03:673 GST] 00002f71 id= DeviceService 3 **create** Response: [{"os":"Android","os_description":"Android 5.0"," model":"ALE-L21","nickname":"demo's ALE-L21","link":"http: //httpservername.companyname.com: 8080/applicationcenter/service/device/e6c6f83ef30e5c1d"," user_display":"****","maker":"HUAWEI","device_id":"e6c6f83ef30e5c122"," os_version":"21","created":"2017-01-13T09:14:03.663Z","updated":"2017- 01-13T09:14:03.663Z","family":"","user_id":"***"}]"

Additional info:
Loadbalancer (443) > ibm httpserver (8080) > Liberty (9080) > db2

Comment: Looks like the App center client is trying to hit ""http: //httpservername.companyname.com: 8080". Is that expected?

Comment: Explained here : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_appres_endpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Ideally 404 comes if the context is not proper. I am not sure if you have changed that. But [in this link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_appres_endpoint.html) you can find an explanation how to properly configure the appcenter server definitions.